# How do i get the two blocks to get horizontally inline?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lost and Found</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav" >
        <img src="img.png" alt="logo" srcset="">
        <div class="b"><span>Electronincs</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Plastics</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Wearables</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Others</span></div>
        <input id="srch" type="search" value="Search">
    </div>

    <div class="main">
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <div class="head">
        <p>Help The Needy</p>
        </div>
        <div class="head">
            <p>Help The Needy</p>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

.nav{
    background-color:bisque;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    position:absolute;
}

.b{
    height: 60px;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    margin: 2px;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
img{
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
}

#srch{
width: 10%;
height:60px;
right: 0%;
position:fixed;
font-size: larger;
}

.main{
   height: 1700px;
   width: 100%;
   border-color: blue;
   border-style: double;
    background-color:lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.head{
    margin-top: 60px;
    display:flexbox;
    width: 45%;
    height: 554px;
    border-color:red;
    border-style: groove;
    border-width: 5;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: larger;
}
```

How do i get the two blocks to get horizontally inline The 2nd block is getting placed vertically below the 1st box.
Also when i set display (which is inline) to inline-block, the blocks suddenly become very thin and still not inlined.

I am beginner web developer trying to learn html and css.
Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap** your elements **within a container** then **use display flex for the container** ... Hope this simple example make it clear

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Some Dummy Text 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Some Dummy Text 2</div>
</div>
```

strong text

Comment: Yes but i have already placed both boxes in a container. And then applied display=inline. But it's still not working. Please Help

Comment: Note that display: inline will display div2-content after div1-content is fully displayed without starting a new line .. display inline is used for displaying elements in the same line instead of starting a new line ..

Hope you get it

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. Having both boxes in the same lines. But it's not happening